# Writing the definition of function which accepts callable function as argument

Tags: c++, c++11

Can anyone help me in writing definition of a function that accepts an STL container and a callable function.  When executed the function applies the callable object to each element of the container?

Comment: Does it return anything?  Is the only thing wrong with `for_each` that it takes iterators, and not a container?  What have you tried, and where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something ultra simple: template a function to accept a container and a function, then call the function on each element:

```
template<typename C, typename F>
void CallCallable(C&& c, F&& f)
{
    for(auto&& element : c)
    {
        f(element);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> myVec{1,2,3,4,5,6};
// add 1 to each element
CallCallable(myVec, [](int& i){++i;});
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/yT4TmI)

Of course this is mighty simple, and I make a few assumptions about what you want, but it gets the job done. (Hopefully someone smarter than me can give you something better :-) )

Comment: You could also just use [boost::for_each](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/for_each.html).

Comment: @JesseGood: Agreed. Thank you for the response. There is also `std::for_each` now, but it appeared that OP wanted to play with writing their own, so that's what I shot for.